# opengl camera on aeroplane shows shaking world when aeroplane is rotated along yaw or pitch or roll

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

i have implemented aeroplane movement in opengl but when i kept camera on aeroplane head and looking at yawaxis its giving shaking world

```cpp
eye = glm::vec3(
    ball1.position.x + 25.0f * ball1.roll_axis.x+ball1.yaw_axis.x,
    ball1.position.y + 25.0f * ball1.roll_axis.y+ball1.yaw_axis.y,
    ball1.position.z + 25.0f * ball1.roll_axis.z+ball1.yaw_axis.z); 
target = glm::vec3(
    ball1.position.x + 60.0f * ball1.roll_axis.x+ball1.yaw_axis.x,
    ball1.position.y + 60.0f * ball1.roll_axis.y+ball1.yaw_axis.y,
    ball1.position.z + 60.0f * ball1.roll_axis.z+ball1.yaw_axis.z);
up = ball1.yaw_axis;
```

aeroplane movement is correct

Comment: What is the question???

Comment: @Masoud how to make this not shake the world. Very clear

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by *gimbal lock*. Check out [accumulative matrix transformations](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/45292/how-is-the-gimbal-locked-problem-solved-using-accumulative-matrix-transformation) or, if You are using GLM [eulerAngleYXZ](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.3/api/a00164.html).